# jQuery - Select everything except a single elements and its children?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to remove everything in the whole body, except of a single element and its children. How can I accomplish this?

**Edit 1**
Consider the following markup:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div id="div1"></div>
      <div id="div2">
         <div id="elementNotToRemove"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="div3"></div>
      <div id="div4"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

In the above example, I want to remove div1, div3 and div4, as well as their children, but conserve div2 because it contains the element not to remove.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
 $("body > *").not("body > #elementtokeep").remove();
```

You can replace the not() part with whatever you want to keep

Comment: But what if the depth of the elements are deeper than just the direct children of the body?

Comment: Removing an element will also remove all children

Comment: Yes, but that's not what I mean. I clarified a bit in the original queston.

Comment: That's exactly what it does. It will only keep div2 and its children

Answer (score 8):

This is an old question, but the accepted answer is wrong. It doesn't work in this situation (see http://jsfiddle.net/LVb3V/ ) and certainly not as a general solution.

Better to use:

`$('body *').not('#div2, #div2 *').remove()​;`

This will remove all elements in the body except for div2 and all the elements it contains.

Comment: Thanks  you!  This should be the accepted solution. The big difference here is the jquery ".not" instead of using not in selector.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it like this:

```
$('body > *:not(#dondelete)').remove();
```

Where your element has `id="dondelete"` and is a child of body.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$('body > *:not(#123)').remove()
```

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Comment: Who upvotes these? This will only select the `body` element itself.

Comment: Now it is the same as other (already correct) solutions posted earlier, so it would be fair to delete yours. I removed the downvote though.

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me.

```
$('body > * :not(#123)').remove()
```

You need to give space between * and : . Earlier when try to use the code with

`$('body > *:not(#123)').remove()`  it did not work. I had to give space between * and : character.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

I think that

```
$("body *").not("body #div2")
           .not("body #div2 #elementtokeep")
           .not("body #div2 #elementtokeep *")
           .remove();
```

is the easiest way to focus it.

http://jsfiddle.net/6vb2va6g/