# jQuery .not() issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

The premise of what I'm trying to do is use jQuery to start a CSS transition to open and close a search box.

User clicks magnifying glass icon, box opens, user clicks anywhere on the page but the search form, box closes.

To close, using this:

```
$('body *').not('#header-search, #header-field, #header-submit').click(function () {
```

And different variations of the answer found here: [jQuery - Select everything except a single elements and its children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173055/jquery-select-everything-except-a-single-elements-and-its-children) without success.

**Clicking on the input#header-field always closes the box.**

Pen Here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNbmwr

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I think you should use a blur event instead. http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Comment: Didn't even think of that, jesus not enough sleep.  Thanks.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very aggressive (*it gets applied to all elements, so inner element to those in the `.not()` will trigger it*).

It is better to delegate the closing of the box to the `body` (*since click events bubble up*), and manually cancel any event that occurs under the forbidden list.

```
$('body').on('click', function(){
   // code for closing box here
});

$('#header-search, #header-field, #header-submit').on('click', function(){
   return false; // stop bubbling of event
});
```

---

And since in your example the `#header-field` and `#header-submit` are descendants of `header-search` you only need to cancel the bubbling on that

```
$('#header-search').on('click', function(){
   return false; // stop bubbling of event
});
```

Demo at http://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/XJrwXO

Comment: maybe you should use `.off('click')` instead of `return false`

Comment: @PabloMatíasGomez, nope. that will not work. `.off()` is to unbind a click handler that has already been bound. Not to stop click events from happening or bubbling up to the `body`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the jQuery toggle() function:

```
<script>
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( "p" ).toggle( "slow" );
});
</script>
```

Substitute the id for your magnifying glass for "button" and change the paragraph -- $("p") -- the search controls you want to show/hide. Toggle changes the visibility of the indicated id or class. If it is initially hidden, mouse click will make it visible; if initially visible, mouse click will hide it.

Finally, change the speed of the transition if you don't want it to move "slow"

A more complete explanation of toggle() is available at http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score -1):

There are many elements on the page. Some of them may contain or be contained by the elements you name. So they will still trigger the event.

Instead, bind a single event handler:

```
$("body").click(function(evt) {
```

and check if you clicked on one of the elements:

```
    if( $(evt.target).parents("#header-search").length > 0) {
```

cancelling the handler if so:

```
        return true;
    }
```

Perform the actual event otherwise:

```
    doSomething();
});
```