# Is there any way to select every element except one in .on() function

Tags: jquery

I am adding a function to all the future created elements of `<div id="content">`

```
<div id="content">
<h3 id="title">tiltle</h3>
</div>
<script>
$("#content").on("click","*",function(){($(this).hide();});
</script>
```

this works fine, but i don't want to bind this function to 
      `<h3  id="title">` I tried

```
 <div id="content">
<h3 id="title">tiltle</h3>
</div>
<script>
$("#content").on("click","*.not('#title')",function(){($(this).hide();});
</script>
```

But this is not working ,  can anyone help me to find efficient solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - Select everything except a single elements and its children?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173055/jquery-select-everything-except-a-single-elements-and-its-children)

Comment: @PhiterFernandes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173055/jquery-select-everything-except-a-single-elements-and-its-children That question does not have a good answer(for me atleast). So I think i can ask same question again if i don't find the answers efficient (for me). I get a very good solution here, but if you say i can delete it as well like my previous 2 question.

Comment: You can use jquery .not() function.

Comment: Pranav  answer is best, it is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)** pseudo-class selector

```
$("#content").on("click",":not(#title)",function(){ 
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: its working ,i tried`" :not('#title')" `. Its working fine . Thanks

Comment: @beginner : glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eorebbss/)

$(function(){

```
$("#content >*").not('#content > #title').on("click",function(){
$(this).hide();
  })
})
```