# Hide all elements except the given data-* attribute with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a menu if someone clicks on one object it should filter all of them accordingly (i.e: all projects, completed projects a.s.o. I have a jQuery to take care of this like this (I added the `.not()` recently, before adding it this script worked):

```
$("#completed").click(function(){
 $('.project_wrapper[data-category="completed_projects"]').not(this).hide();
});
```

I have figured out that I should use `.not()` to `.hide` all objects that don't have the given `[data-category]` or am I doing this wrong?

---

*Edit*

The HTML:

The Menu:

```
<ul class="project_menu>
 <li id="complete">Completed Projects</li>
</ul>
```

The Projects:

```
<div class="project_wrapper" data-category="completed_projects">The projects</div>
```

---

*Edit*
Got it working thanks to @Nitha & @Sam Hollenbach thanks!

Edited a bit myself but here is the final jQuery code I've got:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

 // Show all
 $("#all").click(function(){
   $(".project_wrapper").show();
 });

 // Complete
 $("#complete").click(function(){
   $(".project_wrapper:not([data-category='completed_projects'])").hide();
   $(".project_wrapper[data-category='completed_projects']").show();
 });

});
```

---

*Update*

Instead of using `.show` and `.hide` I used `.css("visibility", "collapse")` & `.css("visibility", "visible")` show and hide seemed to bug out for me in WordPress.

Comment: It would help to see your actual HTML too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below code will hide all the project_wrapper div with data-category not equal to "completed_projects" and will show the project_wrapper div with data-category equal to "completed_projects"

```
$(".project_wrapper:not([data-category='completed_projects'])").hide();
$(".project_wrapper[data-category='completed_projects']").show();
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I'm new to jQuery so this was very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you're asking is to hide all elements within `.project_wrapper` except for the `.project_wrapper[data-category="completed_projects"]` element. In that case I believe you can do this

```
$('.project_wrapper *').not('.project_wrapper[data-category="completed_projects"').hide()​;
```

Or if you want to remove everything in the `body`

`$('body *').not('.project_wrapper[data-category="completed_projects"').hide()​;`

This will remove all elements within `.project_wrapper` or `body`, subtract the one with the correct data-category, and then hide all the others.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11965915/6685140)

Comment: Thank you for your post